# Is it safe to power pi 3 via gpio via ttl cable?

Tags: gpio, power

I hope my question makes sense. I just pruchased a dsd-tech usb to ttl adapter (cp2102 based). It has 3.3v and 5v pins. Is it safe to use the 5 pin to power my pi3 or should i go through micro usb as usual?

[amazon link](http://a.co/d/3fxVYTg)
[dsd-tech controller link](http://www.dsdtech-global.com/search/label/USB%20to%20TTL%20Serial%20Converter)

Thank you!

Comment: I'm sure you'll get a more detailed answer shortly, but the power port has some over-voltage protection or some such that the GPIO does not. Otherwise using GPIO is fine.

Comment: @TomasBy, GPIO is not used for powering the RPi ..... the power pins in the header connector are not part of GPIO

Comment: ["40-pin GPIO header"](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/).

Answer (score 2):

No. USB ports can only supply 500mA (maximum); many adapters less. The Pi needs more current to run reliably.